# Rotating Sphere with Texture iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I know its very basic question but i couldn't find the answer i am looking for. Basically i have to display a rotating 3D sphere on camera overlay. I have got everything except applying texture to that sphere. Here is my code which generate the triangles strips.

```
int createSphere (GLfloat spherePoints[], GLfloat fRadius, GLfloat step){   
    int points = 0;

    GLfloat uStep = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS (step);
    GLfloat vStep = uStep;

    for (GLfloat u = 0.0f; u <= (2 * M_PI); u += uStep) {
      for (GLfloat v = -M_PI_2; v <= M_PI_2; v += vStep) {

        points++;
        spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v) * cosf(u);             // x
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v) * sinf(u);       // y
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v);                 // z

        points++;
        spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v) * cosf(u + uStep);             // x
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v) * sinf(u + uStep);       // y
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v);                         // z

        points++;
        spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * cosf(u);                  // x
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * sinf(u);            // y
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v + vStep);                      // z

        points++;
        spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * cosf(u + uStep);           // x
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * sinf(u + uStep);     // y
        spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v + vStep);                       // z
      }
    }
    return points; 
}
```

Can anybody explain how to generate the Texture coordinates and Normals?

Comment: What's the texture of? Specifically, what projection do you want it to use?

Comment: Post the OpenGL code: where you creating texture, binding it and rendering the scene. This code is useless for the question.

Comment: @tc The texture is of globe with dimensions. 512*1024.

Comment: @Max The above code properly draws a wired sphere for me. This code generates the vertices, How can i edit the same code to generate the normals and texture co-ordinates for me?